# How can I keep the keyboard present even when presenting a modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've got a modal view controller that is presented and a UITextView becomes the first responder and the keyboard is shown.

Once this screen is loaded, the user can categorize their input before submitting it.
This happens by way of another modal view controller that is presented on top.

When this second one is presented, the keyboard is dismissed, the user chooses, and then reappears when the initial UITextView becomes first responder again.

How can I present the second modal view controller without ever dismissing the keyboard?

EDIT: I've implemented part of the UITextViewDelegate, and I'm still not getting the desired result.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `UITextViewDelegate`? In many cases, people forgot this delegate.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor See my updates - I've implemented the one method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.  You'll have to put your modal view in a separate UIWindow, set that second UIWindow's windowLevel to something high (like UIWindowLevelStatusBar), and animate it on and off the screen yourself.  You won't need a second view controller at all.

In your XIB, make a new top-level UIWindow object.  Put your second view into this window.  Connect the window to an outlet on your view controller.  (I called the outlet `otherWindow` in my test code but `overlayWindow` would be a better name.  The outlet needs to be declared `strong` or `retain`.)

In your view controller, implement these methods:

```
- (IBAction)presentOverlay:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
    self.otherWindow.frame = frame;
    self.otherWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    self.otherWindow.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        self.otherWindow.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    }];
}

- (IBAction)dismissOverlay:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
        frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
        self.otherWindow.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL completed){
        self.otherWindow.hidden = YES;
    }];
}
```

Use these to present and dismiss the overlay view.

Comment: The second view controller does not involve using a keyboard. I want the keyboard from the first view to remain popped up even when another view controller is present modally on top of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for that my answer doesn't provide (although I failed to mention that you need your second view controller to define method `canBecomeFirstResponder` to return YES).  My test case keeps the keyboard popped up when I present a view controller modally.

Comment: Please read my comment again - the second controller does not involve the use of a keyboard (its a tableview of about 10 items). The tableview takes up the entire screen, and dismisses when a row is selected. After this controller disappears, it should fall to reveal the keyboard in the first view that was never dismissed.

Comment: Once I add a UIWindow to my XIB and implement this method - the second window is shown, even on the first screen

Comment: Set `self.otherWindow.hidden=YES` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Ahh yes - I set it as Hidden in IB but that would do it also. This does what I want - thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this still the state-of-the-art solution for iOS 7? It seems like something in the SDK, whether it's child view controllers or something else, should enable doing this without mucking with `UIWindow` levels.