# Make keyboard NOT dismiss when opening a ModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep the keyboard present even when presenting a modal view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161207/how-can-i-keep-the-keyboard-present-even-when-presenting-a-modal-view-controller)

I have an opened keyboard on one viewcontroller and I want to show another one. But when I show it, keyboard goes down. But I don't want it to go down. I want it to stay. How can I achieve this? I don't call any endEditings and resignFirstResponders myself.

Comment: Have you tried calling `BecomeFirstResponder` on an editable field in your `ModalViewController`?

Comment: No, I don't want the keyboard to be visible on modal view controller. I want it just to stay on a first one and not jump as it jumps in Apple's Mail App when you call contacts picker.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that in prompts, when created a question.